# How to transform XML layouts uniformly across Android apps?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, code-injection

I am looking into code injection for Android apps (written in Java).  Let's say I have a set of ImageViews declared similarly as such within separate layout files in .../layout/ :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="38dp" />
```

Now let's say I have the following attribute:

```
android:rotation="180"
```

My goal is to add this attribute to every single ImageView in every .xml file in the layout directory on run-time, so that I do not have to edit the source code of these .xml files.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically. What you need to do is to find the image view on activity and call set rotation method and give angle as you are giving in xml file.
   And second way of doing the same thing is you can provide customize style for image view in styles folder of the project.And this will be very simple and far more effective way of doing so. To achieve this via style, you can use below code.

```
 <style name="TitleBarImage">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/lock</item>
    <item name="android:rotation">180</item>
</style>
```

and in every image view, you need to use this below code to get the reflection of style

```
<ImageView style="@style/TitleBarImage" />
```

Hope this will help you.